# Excel: Adding new row to bottom of table, when there are two tables (vertically) in the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a problem which is probably very easy for you to help me solve.

I have two tables: Table1 and Table2. Both tables are in the same worksheet called "Budget".

I want to add a command button / a plus button, that enables a user to add a new row at the bottom of each table.

However, after trying this via the macro record function, I recognized that at some point, the new rows of Table2 are added somewhere in the middle, after having added several new rows to Table1.

Can someone please provide me with a code, that solves this issue and sort of auto-adjusts?

I have never in my life coded something.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Code from recorder:

```
Sub NEWROW() 
' 
' NEWROW Makro 
' 
' 
Range("B12:C12").Select 
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddRows()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim tbl1 As ListObject
    Dim tbl2 As ListObject


    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Set tbl1 = wks.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set tbl2 = wks.ListObjects("Table2")

    tbl1.ListRows.Add
    tbl2.ListRows.Add

End Sub
```

Table object is explained [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)

**Update** Ok, for an absolute beginner this might be the easiest way to do it.

```
Sub AddRowTbl1()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Set tbl = wks.ListObjects("Table1")
    tbl.ListRows.Add

End Sub

Sub AddRowTbl2()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Set tbl = wks.ListObjects("Table2")

    tbl.ListRows.Add
End Sub
```

**PS** A more advanced user would use a function

```
Function tblAddRow(tblname As String, wks As Worksheet)

Dim tbl As ListObject

    On Error GoTo EH

    Set tbl = wks.ListObjects(tblname)
    tbl.ListRows.Add

EH:

End Function

Sub Test_tblAdd()
    tblAddRow "Table1", ActiveSheet
End Sub
```